# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quaternion' problem?

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, package, quaternions

I have downloaded the code for Ronin algorithm implementation from [Sachini/ronin](https://github.com/Sachini/ronin) . While trying to run it with the command

```
python ronin_resnet.py --mode train --train_list <path-to-train-list> --root_dir <path-to-dataset-folder> --out_dir <path-to-output-folder>
```

as mentioned in the ReadMe file I have run into some problems with installing the quaternion library and got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\evgenys2\Desktop\ronin-master\source\ronin_resnet.py", line 14, in <module>
    from data_glob_speed import *
  File "C:\Users\evgenys2\Desktop\ronin-master\source\data_glob_speed.py", line 7, in <module>
    import quaternion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quaternion'
```

[image]

I have tried to do the following commands which I found on google.
`pip install numpy-quaternion`

`pip install quaternion`

`python -c 'import numpy as np; import quaternion'`

```
python -m pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall numpy-quaternion
```

Unfortunately, I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `quaternion` with CONDA instead of PIP, It will solve your problem. I use `quaternion` too, and only conda seemed to install it properly with all the dependencies.

#### Here's how you do it with conda:

###### Add `conda-forge` to your channels:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
```

###### Install `quaternion` by conda:

```
conda install -c conda-forge quaternion
```

In case you don't have **conda** in your system, here's how you install it by following the conda documentation:
[conda-installation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html)

Comment: I just installed anaconda and added to path variables. Pycharm doesnt recognize conda so I have installed quaternion on conda prompt. Pycharm still doesnt recognize quaternion. Do I have to use conda interpreter for it to work?

Comment: yeah, you have to use the conda interpreter, I would advice you to use python from conda only, it's so much better than pip

Comment: I tried changing the interpreter to anaconda and re-installing and it still doesn't work, I got a long error message which doesn't fit in here. It basically says that it wasn't found in the channels.

Comment: that means you need to add the channel first, `conda config --add channels conda-forge` then do the install command

Comment: I have modified the answer with steps to add the channels